# change /dev/sda1 (95% full) to sdb drive

Tags: mount, partition, udev, partition-table

Here is my problem (windows 7 and Linux). They are supposed to be separate but seems they are not.

```
$ df -h --total
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  9.4M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sdb6        48G  7.0G   39G  16% /
tmpfs           7.9G  464K  7.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1       453M  165M  261M  39% /boot
/dev/sdb7        48G  7.7G   38G  17% /home
tmpfs           1.6G  104K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda1       120G  113G  6.6G  95% /media/ken/5A50B44C50B4309D
total           243G  128G  110G  54% -
```

`/dev/sda1` is in the windows 7 folder somehow.  I want to change this to sdb drive which has space. Maybe a `cp` copy of `/dev/sda1` to a new `/dev/sdbx`?

I'm not even sure why this shows `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sda1`.
Maybe Linux is not using `/dev/sda1`?   How can I check?

Any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: Output from partition-listing tools might be useful, to see what partitions and of what type are where on what disks...

Answer (score 1):

Linux has mounted your windows partition as `/media/ken/5A50B44C50B4309D`, which is your Windows partition on your first drive (`sda1`). Your Linux machine is using a separate drive (`sdb`).

If your goal is to free up space on your Windows partition by copying files to your Linux partitions, absolutely you can do that. But you'll have to find the files to move (`mv` command).

With regards to your concern about Windows and Linux being separate: rest assured, they are. All of your Linux partitions are on your second drive (`sdb`) and Windows is happily on your first (`sda`). Your confusion might be that Linux is mounting your Windows partition for you to access your Windows files from Linux if you desire.